# Matching Chapters to a Custom posts

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, posts, advanced-custom-fields

Im beginner in WordPress ...

I have a Custom post type (using CPT UI plugin) called Stories which contain fields (using ACF plugin) to fill up  story general info including the title , synopsis , language ,genre etc.. Also, I made another Custom post called Story Chapter where I enter the Chapter number and the chapter content .

What I want to do is to link the Story Chapter with Story , whereas when I add a chapter its automatically added to its Story. In other words , for example , I have a lots of Stories posts and I want a way in which hen i add a story Chapter post its automatically goes to its story .

So is there a field or settings in ACF or CPT UI plugin which can help me to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might be a question best answered by the authors of the plugins. There are so many plugins for WordPress that general WordPress experts might, collectively, lack any experience of your particular plugins. Which is why the community considers third-party plugins to be off-topic. I truly hope you find the answers you need even if that turns out not to be from here.